# How to get only string resources in c#?

Tags: c#, string, localization, resources

I need to get only string resources from resource files. How can I get only string resources ?
I am using ResXResourceReader for reading resources. For iterating through each resources I used

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resReader)
```

Here resReader is a ResXResourceReader object.Thanks for the help in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Why not just skip the non-Strings?

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resReader) {
    if (!(dictionaryEntry.Value is String)) continue;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: throws an exception on the line
foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resReader)
before the if statement..

Comment: Telerik.Web.UI.BinaryImageCropPosition throws an exception for this type of resources..how to exclude them ?

Comment: {"ResX file Type Telerik.Web.UI.BinaryImageCropPosition, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.2.611.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4 in the data at line 604, position 4 cannot be located. Line 606, position 5. cannot be parsed."}

Comment: Does this occur for any ressoures or for a specific ressourse entry? How did you process the `DictionaryEntry` in the original loop?

Comment: for any resources with type Telerik.Web.UI.BinaryImageCropPosition.
    foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resReader)
    resWriter.AddResource((string)dictionaryEntry.Key, (string)dictionaryEntry.Value);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hstWords = new Hashtable();
using (var resxFile = new ResXResourceReader(objFile))
{
    var lstItems = resxFile.GetEnumerator();
    while (lstItems.MoveNext())
        hstWords.Add(Convert.ToString(lstItems.Key).ToUpper(), lstItems.Value);
    resxFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting a way. throws an exception for Telerik.Web.UI.BinaryImageCropPosition type resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try

```
     ResXResourceReader myResources = new ResXResourceReader(@"path/to/your/file");
     foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in myResources.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList().Where(x => x.Value.GetType() == typeof(string)))
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Value); // ...
```

Comment: what is resources here ?

Comment: Hi, try without the first line
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resReader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList().Where(x=> x.Value.GetType() == typeof(string)))

It should work.

Comment: TRIED IT..doesn't work..throws the same exception..if you want I can send you the resource file to check..